# React Native - BleManager.startNotification is not working

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using react native with the library 'react-native-ble-manager'. Sofar I can connect to the hardware, send some commands to the hardware, but I can't receive any values, simple JSON data, from the hardware. I just can't make the BleManager.startNotification work.
My procedure is following, I connect to ble device, send a command to the ble device and after pushing the button on react-native software to receive data I start a function handleReceiveData, see the code below.

```
const handleReceiveData = async () => {
    // Find the connected peripheral you want to receive data from
    const connectedPeripheral = Array.from(peripherals.values()).find(
      p => p.connected,
    );

    if (!connectedPeripheral) {
      console.log('No connected peripheral found for receiving data');
      return;
    }

    try {
      await BleManager.retrieveServices(connectedPeripheral.id).then(
        peripheralInfo => {
          // Success code
          console.log('Peripheral info:', peripheralInfo);
        },
      );
      // Start notification on the characteristic
      await BleManager.startNotification(
        connectedPeripheral.id,
        SERVICE_UUID,
        CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
      )
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Started notification on ' + CHARACTERISTIC_UUID);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Notification error', error);
        });

      // Set up an event listener for when characteristic value updates
      bleManagerEmitter.addListener(
        'BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic',
        ({value, peripheral, characteristic, service}) => {
          // Check if this is the right characteristic
          if (
            peripheral === connectedPeripheral.id &&
            characteristic === CHARACTERISTIC_UUID
          ) {
            // Convert bytes array to string
            const dataAsString = value
              .map((byte: number) => String.fromCharCode(byte))
              .join('');
            setReceivedData(dataAsString);
            console.log('Received data: ', dataAsString);
          }
        },
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to set up data reception', error);
    }
  };
```

I receive all the timne an error called:  **LOG  Set notification failed for 6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e**

[image]

My ble device is working fine. I tested everything with the app "nRF Connect" Here is the pic with received data.
[image]

Comment: Do you get any log output? If yes, please [edit] your question to add it as well

Comment: I edited my questions with all possible info.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: [Version 11.0.7](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager/releases/tag/v.11.0.7) of `react-native-ble-manager` includes [a fix for the underlying issue](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager/pull/1144).

---

This question was first answered on the OP's [cross-post to GitHub](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager/issues/1132#issuecomment-1853559758). Cross-posting [the answer](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager/issues/1132#issue-2033697395) here:

> I can successfully connect to my Bluetooth devices by compressing my known 128-bit UUIDs on iOS to their shorter 16-bit versions prior to calling startNotification.
>
> > Note:
> >
> > This code only handles 16-bit UUIDs. Based on the docs for CBUUID (see Additional context), it looks like a full solution would also need to support 32-bit UUIDs
>
> ```js
> function compressUUID(uuid: string): string {
>   // Bluetooth 4.0 specification, Volume 3, Part F, Section 3.2.1
>   // https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=456433
>
>   // Required since react-native-ble-manager needs short UUIDs for notifications on
>   // iOS, so I need to be able to compare them to the full UUIDs known for my devices.
>   
>   // CBUUID (iOS):
>   // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbuuid
>   // Source: https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager/blob/f46dd5c303ea0e70a44e299fb1ebabff86da9edd/ios/BleManager.swift#L381-L385
>   const baseUUID = /0000(....)-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB/;
>   if (baseUUID.test(uuid.toUpperCase())) {
>     return uuid.substring(4, 8);
>   } else {
>     return uuid;
>   }
> }
>
> BleManager.startNotification(
>     "189fd3cb-fb2b-a6a6-b214-246d82f81298",
>     compressUUID("0000aadb-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"),
>     compressUUID("0000aadc-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"),
> )
> ```